# What version running in iOS and Android in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Currently, we are developing with Kivy 1.10.0 and Python 3.4.4 on Windows.
At the time of Build, I plan to build it through Linux in the virtual environment.
In order to run on both iOS and Android, what version do I need for both Kivy and Python in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what Kivy version you have installed locally (a new one will be built for Android), and both python2.7 or python3.5+ should work.